# How do i iterate over large Mongo collections without OutOfMemoryError

Tags: java, mongodb, spring-boot, spring-data

In my Spring application i want to iterate over a Mongo collection to perform some work with each entry. The collection can be quite large so can't simply get a list of all entries as that would result in OutOfMemoryErrors.

My latest attempt is this:

```
void m(MongoOperations ops, Set<String> ids) {
   Query query = new Query().addCriteria(Criteria.where("id").in(ids));
   CloseableIterator<Foo> it = ops.stream(query, Foo.class);
   it.forEachRemaining(foo -> {
       System.out.println(foo.getName());
   }
}
```

It suprised me to see that i am getting OutOfMemoryErrors here. It looks like all entries of Foo that match the query are loaded into memory as soon as `it.forEachRemaining` is called.

A Heapdump shows that the `CloseableIteratorAdaptor` holds a `DBCursor` which holds a `QueryResultIterator` which in turn holds an *ArrayList* with all entries.

Am i doing something wrong? 
Is `stream()` always loading all entries into memory?
Do i have to implement paging?

Here is the relevant part of my heap dump's dominator tree.

```
Class Name                                                                                                           | Shallow Heap | Retained Heap | Percentage
-----------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
org.example.server.OrganizationScopedThreadFactory$OrganizationScopedThread @ 0x81f71718  pool-1-thread-1 Thread|          128 | 1,453,308,456 |     87,50%
|- org.springframework.data.mongodb.core.MongoTemplate$CloseableIterableCursorAdapter @ 0x8b2df1c0                   |           24 | 1,432,708,656 |     86,26%
|  |- com.mongodb.DBCursor @ 0x8b3bb0f8                                                                              |           96 | 1,432,708,600 |     86,26%
|  |  |- com.mongodb.QueryResultIterator @ 0x8b5e7c70                                                                |           72 | 1,431,064,320 |     86,16%
|  |  |  |- java.util.ArrayList$Itr @ 0x8b5e7cb8                                                                     |           32 | 1,431,064,152 |     86,16%
|  |  |  |  '- java.util.ArrayList @ 0x8b5e7cd8                                                                      |           24 | 1,431,064,120 |     86,16%
|  |  |  |     '- java.lang.Object[30391] @ 0x8b5e8ed8                                                               |      121,584 | 1,431,064,096 |     86,16%
|  |  |  |        |- com.mongodb.BasicDBObject @ 0x8c2eed70                                                          |           64 |       123,528 |      0,01%
|  |  |  |        |  |- java.util.LinkedHashMap$Entry @ 0x8c2eef18                                                   |           40 |       122,240 |      0,01%
|  |  |  |        |  |  |- com.mongodb.BasicDBList @ 0x8c2eef78                                                      |           32 |       122,144 |      0,01%
|  |  |  |        |  |  |  '- java.lang.Object[10] @ 0x8c2eef98                                                      |           56 |       122,112 |      0,01%
|  |  |  |        |  |  |     '- com.mongodb.DBRef @ 0x8c2eefd0                                                      |           32 |       122,056 |      0,01%
|  |  |  |        |  |  |        |- com.mongodb.BasicDBObject @ 0xc5dbc778                                           |           64 |       121,992 |      0,01%
|  |  |  |        |  |  |        |- org.bson.types.ObjectId @ 0x8c2eeff0                                             |           32 |            32 |      0,00%
|  |  |  |        |  |  |        '- Total: 2 entries                                                                 |              |               |           
|  |  |  |        |  |  |- java.lang.String @ 0x8c2eef40  projects                                                   |           24 |            56 |      0,00%
|  |  |  |        |  |  '- Total: 2 entries                                                                          |              |               |           
|  |  |  |        |  |- java.util.LinkedHashMap$Entry @ 0x8c2eee00                                                   |           40 |         1,024 |      0,00%
|  |  |  |        |  |- java.util.LinkedHashMap$Entry @ 0x8c2eeea0                                                   |           40 |           120 |      0,00%
|  |  |  |        |  |- java.util.HashMap$Node[16] @ 0x8c2eedb0                                                      |           80 |            80 |      0,00%
|  |  |  |        |  '- Total: 4 entries                                                                             |              |               |           
|  |  |  |        |- com.mongodb.BasicDBObject @ 0x8bcfd4c0                                                          |           64 |       123,480 |      0,01%
|  |  |  |        |- com.mongodb.BasicDBObject @ 0x8c48e2c8                                                          |           64 |       113,520 |      0,01%
|  |  |  |        |- com.mongodb.BasicDBObject @ 0x8c66f668                                                          |           64 |       112,296 |      0,01%
|  |  |  |        |- com.mongodb.BasicDBObject @ 0x8c87afe0                                                          |           64 |       112,120 |      0,01%
|  |  |  |        |- com.mongodb.BasicDBObject @ 0x8c521008                                                          |           64 |       106,096 |      0,01%
|  |  |  |        |- com.mongodb.BasicDBObject @ 0x8cdc68d0                                                          |           64 |        99,576 |      0,01%
|  |  |  |        |- com.mongodb.BasicDBObject @ 0x8c8efa40                                                          |           64 |        90,456 |      0,01%
|  |  |  |        |- com.mongodb.BasicDBObject @ 0x8b8e0d18                                                          |           64 |        77,600 |      0,00%
|  |  |  |        |- com.mongodb.BasicDBObject @ 0x8bbc5a30                                                          |           64 |        77,600 |      0,00%
|  |  |  |        |- com.mongodb.BasicDBObject @ 0x8bc446e8                                                          |           64 |        77,600 |      0,00%
|  |  |  |        |- com.mongodb.BasicDBObject @ 0x8bcc0ca0                                                          |           64 |        77,600 |      0,00%
|  |  |  |        |- com.mongodb.BasicDBObject @ 0x8bda1d30                                                          |           64 |        77,600 |      0,00%
|  |  |  |        |- com.mongodb.BasicDBObject @ 0x8be46048                                                          |           64 |        77,600 |      0,00%
|  |  |  |        |- com.mongodb.BasicDBObject @ 0x8be462e8                                                          |           64 |        77,600 |      0,00%
|  |  |  |        |- com.mongodb.BasicDBObject @ 0x8beb24f8                                                          |           64 |        77,600 |      0,00%
|  |  |  |        |- com.mongodb.BasicDBObject @ 0x8beb2798                                                          |           64 |        77,600 |      0,00%
|  |  |  |        |- com.mongodb.BasicDBObject @ 0x8bee79d0                                                          |           64 |        77,600 |      0,00%
|  |  |  |        |- com.mongodb.BasicDBObject @ 0x8bf04f38                                                          |           64 |        77,600 |      0,00%
|  |  |  |        |- com.mongodb.BasicDBObject @ 0x8bf0eae8                                                          |           64 |        77,600 |      0,00%
|  |  |  |        |- com.mongodb.BasicDBObject @ 0x8bf0ed88                                                          |           64 |        77,600 |      0,00%
|  |  |  |        |- com.mongodb.BasicDBObject @ 0x8bf14220                                                          |           64 |        77,600 |      0,00%
|  |  |  |        |- com.mongodb.BasicDBObject @ 0x8bf3edf0                                                          |           64 |        77,600 |      0,00%
|  |  |  |        |- com.mongodb.BasicDBObject @ 0x8bf78640                                                          |           64 |        77,600 |      0,00%
|  |  |  |        |- com.mongodb.BasicDBObject @ 0x8bf7dd30                                                          |           64 |        77,600 |      0,00%
|  |  |  |        '- Total: 25 of 30.276 entries; 30.251 more                                                        |              |               |           
-----------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
```

**Update:**
I have since tried implementing paging by setting a limit to the query and sorting it and then repeatedly skip entries until i have iterated over everything. While this does take care of my memory issues, it significantly reduces performance (about 100 times slower), probably due to the need for sorting.

I am using Spring Boot 1.3.7

Comment: can you share your replica set configuration ? rs.status() output ? also are the primary and the secondarys in the same data center ?

Comment: Are you sure the cursor has that memory issue? The cursor is designed to work in two modes: Array or iterator. In the array mode it fetches everything and stores it in an arraylist but in the iterator mode it fetches them in batches and doesn't keep them in memory. The Spring-data ClosableIterator implementation doesn't make any calls to the toArray() mode. So technically it shouldn't be rooted there. Why don't you add your heap dump here as well so that we can have a look.

Comment: I don't think i have a replica set configuration. When calling `mongoClient.getReplicaSetStatus()` `null` is returned. I have added parts of the heap dump to the original question.

Comment: Have you tried using a more recent version of the Java Driver? Looks like `QueryResultIterator` doesn't exist in 3.x versions anymore. I checked the Spring Data sources and we don't call any of the pre-loading methods AFAICS.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

A memory limit of 16 MB is applied for cursor, you might need to write application level looping to pick batches of say 1000 by using skip and limit and sorting.

First pick 1000, then 1000 to 2000 and so on until the end of documents, make sure to use sorting in query so that data is consistent.

Also you have to be mindful if you are going to modify the field on which you are querying and sorting so that same data does not keep popping up again and again.

Comment: I'm afraid i don't understand. What is this 16 MB limit? How does it relate to the 1.5 GB of heap space my cursor uses in the above example?

Comment: Well MongoDB server puts a limit on the cursor which is returned by the find() call more in my opinion as a sanity check, it means it can load in memory only that much data for one query call.

It has nothing(little) to do with your operating system memory .